# Mongo $addToSet still inserting despite item in array existing

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to insert a new array item into an array of objects using $addToSet as I don't want duplicates

```
    var location = {
    place : req.body.location.Place,
    postcode : req.body.location.Postcode
}
User.update({_id: req.body._id},
         {$addToSet: { 'locations' : location}}, function(err, data) { 

});
```

This inserts a record every time even if place and postcode exactly match.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show some duplicate results here?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your results are not the same (they might look the same, but have invisible characters). For example:

```
db.a.insert({_id : 1, locs: []});
```

And then no matter how many times do you addToSet objects to the array locs:

```
db.a.update({_id : 1},{$addToSet : {
   locs: {a : 1, b: 2}
}})
```

Only the first one will be added.

So take a look at what are you adding, then try to do a raw mongo shell attempt. If it does not work correctly, post it here. Otherwise look more precisely at the data your app is providing to mongo.

Comment: Yeah your example works fine but I am getting this added to every item i place in the array             
        "_id": {
                "$oid": "5428f2fe813693cc26803220"
            }
        }
Which I assume is the fact that the array contains an object 

"locations": [
        {
            "place": "Llandudno",
            "postcode": "ll30",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5428f2fe813693cc26803220"
            }
        },
]

Comment: @RobPaddock most probably mongoose is adding this $oid. No idea why is it doing it (not familiar with mongoose). Just find out the way to remove it.

Comment: Yeah it was I had to create a schema for it and set the _id to false. Thanks for the help though trying it in terminal made it easy to track the problem down.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help Salvador
It seems as I'm using Mongoose it adds the _id, I needed to create a subDocument or new schema for the array and set the _id to false

```
locations : [new mongoose.Schema(
    { 
        place : String,
        postcode : String
    },
    { _id: false})
]
```

All working fine now